# Selenium - response data does not contain certain elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page

https://www.tribeofdumo.com/product-page/gbemi-dress-purple

and in particular I'm trying to get the list of sizes in the dropdown menu by accessing the element `<div class ='option-selection-item'>`.

I can see this element when doing an inspect element, however in the response data from `Selenium` I am unable to locate this element. So how do I go about extracting the  data from the sizes dropdown?

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import re
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.tribeofdumo.com/product-page/gbemi-dress-purple")
sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame("TPAMultiSection_jc31t3yyiframe")
sleep(10)
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you meant to do the following. However, It produces the different size available in that dropdown:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tribeofdumo.com/product-page/gbemi-dress-purple")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("TPAMultiSection_jc31t3yyiframe"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select2-arrow").click()
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ui-select-container .option-selection-item"):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
S
M
L
XL
2XL
```